# Listas circulares simples, contar y mostrar

Tags: java

es mi primera pregunta dentro de esta comunidad y de antemano agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

En este momento tengo la necesidad en Java de contar los elementos de una lista circular simple que coincidan con un parámetro y mostrar dicha cantidad en pantalla, así también tengo la necesidad de mostrar los juegos en base a otro parámetro, en este caso el precio. De esta manera debo desarrollar los siguientes métodos en Java

```
    Public int contar (String plataforma){
    }
    Public void mostrar (int precio){
    }
```

Como referencia mi lista está compuesta por los siguientes elementos.

```
    Lista_circular lista = new Lista_circular();
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Deportes", "PES 2015", "PS3", 30, 7.8f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "God of War SAGA", "PS3", 40, 8.7f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Supervivencia", "The Last of US", "PS3", 60, 9.2f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "GTA V", "PS3", 60, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Indie", "Inside + Limbo", "PS4", 70, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "Bioshock - The Collection", "PS4", 55, 9.0f));
```

Dentro de la clase Lista_circular tengo lo siguiente.

```
public class Lista_circular {
private Nodo cabeza, ultimo;


//Método encargado de insertar juegos en la lista circular
public void inserta(Juego j){
    //si el valor de cabeza es nulo, es decir, la lista está vacía el juego
    //toma el valor de j
    if (cabeza == null){
        cabeza = new Nodo (j); 
        //a la vez el último es el primero dentro de la lista
        ultimo = cabeza;
        //se establece que el ultimo tiene como siguiente a cabeza
        ultimo.setNext(cabeza);
    //si ya hay un valor en cabeza al momento de agregar un juego
    }else{
        //el juego a ingresar se acomoda de tal manera que el precio menor 
        //vaya a la izquierda del ya ingresado         
        if(j.getPrecio() < cabeza.getDato().getPrecio()){
            //se crea un aux para unir los juegos
            Nodo aux = new Nodo (j); 
            aux.setNext(cabeza);
            cabeza = aux;
            //con esto hacemos la lista circular   
            ultimo.setNext(cabeza); 
            //para insertar todos los datos mayor
        }else{ 
            //valida si el precio del nuevo juego a insertar tiene un precio
            //mayor al último ingresado
            if (j.getPrecio() >= ultimo.getDato().getPrecio()){ 
                //No se pueden unir nodos y juegos, por ello crearemos el nodo auxiliar
                Nodo aux = new Nodo (j);
                ultimo.setNext(aux);
                ultimo = aux; 
                ultimo.setNext(cabeza); //circular de nuevo 
                //para insertar en el medio de la estructura
            }else{ 
                Nodo aux = cabeza;
                while(j.getPrecio() > aux.getNext().getDato().getPrecio() ){ //el precio del juego es mayor al siguiente del auxiliar
                    aux = aux.getNext(); 
                }
                Nodo temp = new Nodo (j); //creamos el dato temporal para guardar el juego entre dos precios, una vez cerrado el ciclo
                //se une primero el juego menor con el mayor para no perder la listya
                temp.setNext(aux.getNext());
                aux.setNext(temp); //se une el menor con el mayor en dicha comparacion
            }  
        }
    }
```

}

```
//Método encargado de validar si un juego existe dentro de la lista
public boolean existe (String nombre){
    String mensaje;
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista no contiene datos";
    } else {
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
                existe = true;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
    return existe;
}

//Método encargado de moficiar en base a nombre y plataforma
public void modifica (String nombre, String plataforma){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    }
    else {
        if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre()) && plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma()) ){
            aux.getDato().setPuntaje(10);
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre()) && plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma()) ) {
                aux.getDato().setPuntaje(10);
                existe = true;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
    if (existe == false) {
        System.out.println("No existe un juego con las caracteristicas indicadas");
    }
}

//Método encargado de eliminar en base a categoria y nombre
public void elimina (String categoria, String nombre){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    } else {
        if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            cabeza = aux.getNext();
            ultimo.setNext(cabeza);
            existe = true;
        } else if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
            aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (categoria.equals(aux.getDato().getCategoria()) && nombre.equals(aux.getDato().getNombre())) {
                aux.setNext(aux.getNext().getNext());
                existe = true;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
    if (existe == false) {
        System.out.println("No existe un juego que coincida con la categoria y nombre indicados");
    }
}

//Método encargado de contar los elementos que coincidan con plataforma
public int contar (String plataforma){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    int cont = 0;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    }else{                        
        if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())){
            cont++;
            existe = true;
        } else {
            aux = aux.getNext();
            while (aux != cabeza) {
                if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {                        
                    existe = true;  
                }
                cont++;
                aux = aux.getNext();
            }
                }
        if (existe == false) {
            System.out.println("No existen juegos de dicha plataforma");
            return 0;
            }                        
        }
    return cont;
```

}

```
//Método encargado de mostrar en base al precio
public void mostrar (int precio){
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    }else{
        if (precio == aux.getDato().getPrecio()){
            System.out.println(aux.getDato().getPrecio());
        }
    }
}



//Imprime en consola
 @Override
public String toString() {
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    String s = "Lista: \n ";
    if (aux != null) {
        s += aux + ", \n ";
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            s += aux + ", \n ";
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        s+= "Vacia";
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

Así tengo dentro del **main** lo siguiente que me permite imprimir en consola los distintos métodos creados.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Lista_circular lista = new Lista_circular();
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Deportes", "PES 2015", "PS3", 30, 7.8f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "God of War SAGA", "PS3", 40, 8.7f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Supervivencia", "The Last of US", "PS3", 60, 9.2f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "GTA V", "PS3", 60, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Indie", "Inside + Limbo", "PS4", 70, 8.3f));
    lista.inserta(new Juego ("Aventura", "Bioshock - The Collection", "PS4", 55, 9.0f));
    //Lista circular original
    System.out.println("---LISTA ORIGINAL---");
    System.out.println(lista.toString());
    //Buscar un juego con el nombre
    System.out.println("---BUSQUEDA DE JUEGO BASADO EN EL NOMBRE---");
    System.out.println("¿El juego ingresado existe? \n"+lista.existe("PES 2018"));
    System.out.println("\n");
    //Modifica el puntaje de un juego dado un nombre y plataforma
    System.out.println("---MODIFICACIÓN DEL PUNTAJE BASADO EN 2 CAMPOS---");
    System.out.println("Modificación del puntaje dado un juego y plataforma dado");
    lista.modifica("Inside + Limbo", "PS4");
    System.out.println("Lista después de modificación:\n" + lista);        
   //Elimina un juego dada una categoría y un nombre
    System.out.println("---ELIMINACIÓN DE JUEGO BASADO EN EL NOMBRE---");
    System.out.println("Elimina por ID");
    lista.elimina("Deportes", "PES 2015");
    System.out.println("Lista después de eliminación:\n"+lista);
    //Indica cuantos juegos existen de una plataforma
    System.out.println("---CONTEO DE JUEGOS SEGÚN PLATAFORMA---");
    System.out.println("Para la plataforma indicada se encontraron: "  +lista.contar("PS3"));
    //
    System.out.println("", +lista.mostrar(7));

}
```

Sin embargo, cuando imprimo el método contar, obtengo como resultado un número diferente a lo esperado, dentro de lo normal sería que si coloco "PS3" como parámetro debería devolverme que existen 4 juegos dentro de la lista que coinciden con lo indicado, sin embargo, el resultado me devuelve uno, y si coloco "PS4" dentro del parámetro me devuelve como resultado 4

---CONTEO DE JUEGOS SEGÚN PLATAFORMA---
Para la plataforma indicada se encontraron: 4

Con respecto al método mostrar debería de mostrarme cada uno de los juegos que coincidan con un precio menor o igual al indicado e imprimirme esos juegos en pantalla, pero de igual manera acá el método no me deja introducir el precio que deseo y obtengo como error en el main

"void type not allowed here"

Comment: Para entenderlo bien, entonces quieres contar los objetos dentro de esa lista que tienen el atributo X, y luego escribir en pantalla los objetos que tienen el atributo Y, ¿no?

Comment: Sí exacto, necesito contar los objetos dentro de dicha lista que contengan el atributo X, en este caso la plataforma y mostrar en pantalla la cantidad de elementos que coinciden con dicho atributo. Y en el caso del segundo método necesito mostrar en pantalla los que coincidan con un precio menor o igual al recibido

Comment: Como se ha dicho, por favor, reformula mejor la pregunta, y se ve que usas una clase propia llamada `Lista_circular` así que por favor indica el código que tiene esta clase para poder ayudarte mejor a menos que desees que esto se haga con `List` o alguno de sus hijos

Comment: Listo, creo que he editado la publicación original con lo conlleva la clase Lista_circular, gracias por tu tiempo @NeoChiri

Comment: Sí correcto, ya existen pero no hacen la función que tengo encomendada, no me cuenta los juegos que coincidan con la plataforma que indico dentro del main, y tampoco me muestra los juegos que coinciden con el método que valora si el precio es menor o igual a uno indicado

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, creo que ahora sí edite mi pregunta con los datos necesarios, espero me puedas ayudar ya que no se que más hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos...

El metodo contar tiene un grave defecto de logica.

Si tu primer item es el que estas buscando, no contas mas y dejas de buscar.

```
public int contar (String plataforma){
...
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    }else{    
    //Aca esta el problema.. si el primero es lo que buscas, ya te fuiste.                    
    if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())){
        cont++;
        existe = true;
    } else {
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {                        
                existe = true;  
            }
            cont++;
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
```

Solucion muy rapida a esto.. Saca el else (y el codigo del else va afuera del if), y va a andar a la perfeccion sin que te des cuenta por que (y como tarea, trata de entender el porque).

Tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

```
public int contar (String plataforma){
...
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    }else{    
    //Aca esta el problema.. si el primero es lo que buscas, ya te fuiste.                    
    if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())){
        cont++;
        existe = true;
    } 
    aux = aux.getNext();
    while (aux != cabeza) {
        if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {                        
            existe = true;  
        }
        cont++;
        aux = aux.getNext();
    }
```

---

La funcion mostrar, no hace nada de nada.. pero que casualidad, la funcion contar tiene la misma logica, solo que en lugar de mostrar, cuenta..

Y si, digamos, usas el codigo de la funcion contar.. pero en lugar de contar (o sea sumar al cont++), mostras????

Luego de un par de revisiones, finalmente el código del método contar quedó de la siguiente manera.

```
    public int contar(String plataforma) {
    String mensaje = "";
    boolean existe = false;
    Nodo aux = cabeza;
    int cont = 0;
    if (cabeza == null) {
        mensaje = "La lista está vacía";
    } else {

        if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {
            cont++;
            existe = true;
        }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        while (aux != cabeza) {
            if (plataforma.equals(aux.getDato().getPlataforma())) {
                existe = true;
                cont++;
            }
            aux = aux.getNext();
        }
        if (existe == false) {
            System.out.println("No existen juegos de dicha plataforma");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Ahora solo me queda terminar el de mostrar y quedaría listo

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuando dices, sacar el else (y el código del else va a fuera del if), ¿podrías explicarme mejor?

Comment: si. Todo lo que esta adentro del else, es lo que efectivamente recorre la lista... deja.. te edito esa parte del codigo...

Comment: Encontré **[esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zNwA.png)** tirado... ¿puede ser que se te haya perdido a vos @gbianchi?